# Permission error when logging in to a node without SSH password

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

```
hadoop@ubuntu01:~$ cat ./id_rsa.pub >> /.authorized_keys
bash: /.authorized_keys: Permission denied
```

I have looked for many ways, but none of them work.

my system is ubuntu18.04

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just have to type:

```
su -
```

Insert your root password and then you can cat authorized keys, but remember to be careful since you're root now